# This page isn’t working HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, forms, web, php-7.1

I am trying to use a php post method in my  project but I don't know why it isn't working.

Basically I have 2 pages: `index.php` and `data.php`

From `index.php` a php form is there through which one can enter his details and click submit , the other page data.php should retrieve it but it isn't doing so.I'm getting error

> This page isn't working ... HTTP ERROR 500

**index.php**

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="data.php" method="post">
        Enter your tt: <input type="text" name="token"><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/67wzzqpc/)

**data.php**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['token'])){
    $abc = explode('token=',$_POST['token']);

    if($abc[1]){

        $test = explode('&expires_in=',$abc[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        $test[0] =$_POST['token'];
    }

    include 'qwert1.php';
}

else{}

$titror ='?><script>alert("Sorry, Its Invalid");document.location="/";</script><?';

?>
```

[JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/g6ahh5ou/3/)

Comment: I'd suggest where you have a short code sample that shows the problem(your code wasn't that long) include it in your post.

Comment: This error message + no syntax errors -> **protip:** restart browser ;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update this:

```
$titror ='?><script>alert("Sorry, Its Invalid");document.location="/";</script><?';
```

to this:

```
?><script>alert("Sorry, Its Invalid");document.location="/";</script>
```

You cant start a string:

```
$titror = '
```

and close php tag.

Answer (score 0):

Line 8 of data.php has:

```
$tes = explode('&expires_in=',$abc[1]);
```

$tes should read $test.